# TikZ wrong perspective?

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

The perspective looks wrong. What's going on? 
(Also, feel free to comment on anything that could be improved.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagecolor{darkgray}\color{white}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale = 5,
  rotate around y = 50,
  dot/.style = {
    fill, draw, circle,
    inner sep = 0,
    minimum size = 2pt,
  }
]

  \node [dot] (O) at (0, 0, 0) {};
  \filldraw [
    color = green,
    fill opacity = 0.25,
  ]
    (1,0,0) node [dot] (i) {} --
    (0,1,0) node [dot] (j) {} --
    (0,0,1) node [dot] (k) {} --
    cycle;
  \draw [->] (O) -- ($1.3*(i)$);
  \draw [->] (O) -- ($1.3*(j)$);
  \draw [->] (O) -- ($1.3*(k)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: bad perspective]

Here is a version with a rotation of `30` instead.

[image: bad perspective rot 30]

The objective is the one below.

[image: correct perspective]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "looks wrong".

Comment: Just added my expectation, so now it should be clearer. Thanks for the prompt for question improvement.

Comment: TikZ uses _isometric projection_ ...

Comment: Oh, I see. Is any way to change that to “I don't know what I need” projection?

Comment: What you mostly need is some extra space on the left side.  Try `\path (current bounding box.west) ++(-10pt,0);` at the end of the tikzpicture.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, I don't think that's a problem at all. This is an illustration that will be added to a document *within* LaTeX. To add a margin for "exporting" this figure, one could add `border=10pt` to the `standalone` `documentclass` as shown in @hpekristiansen's answer.

Comment: @Atcold: As your objective has been fulfilled(as I see it) by my answer, it is difficult to see how your question has not been answered. You could update your question to make it more clear. If you just leave it hanging, it will most likely be closed.

Comment: @hpekristiansen, see my last comment to your answer.

Comment: @Atcold: You need to update your question, accept the answer or your question most likely will be closed.

Comment: My question is asking «What's going on?». @PaulGaborit correctly pointed out it's an *isometric projection*. You also said, in a comment to your answer, that you «did a direct comparison of compiled result and the wished result and stepped the parameters in steps of 0.1 until the result had smallest error». If you can add this context I'll gladly accept your answer. Right now it's unclear *how* you solved my issue.

Comment: @PaulGaborit, you were mistaken. TikZ uses a *cabinet perspective*. I've added a correction and a citation in the accepted answer.

Comment: @Atcold You are right: the correct name is _cabinet perspective_. I wanted to clarify that TikZ uses perspective without vanishing points.

Comment: LOL, I realised I messed up the terms as well! TikZ uses *parallel projection* rather than a *perspective*. All clear now!

Comment: If you use Asymptote https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/ you can enjoy perspective and orthographic projections

Comment: Oh, wow, impressive! At first glance, the code seems more “compact” than TikZ (maybe because it's an actual language and not a collection of macros). I understand this is an external program that would simply generate PDF files for me to include in the LaTeX document, correct? Thanks a bunch for the pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP's question was answered in the comments, I'll compile a summary for future users.

OP: Does TikZ has a wrong perspective? What's going on? 
@PaulGaborit: TikZ uses isometric projection…

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_projection) we learn that this is wrong.

> [An isometric projection] is an axonometric projection in which the three coordinate axes appear **equally foreshortened** and the angle between any two of them is **120 degrees**.

Instead, TikZ uses a *cabinet parallel projection*. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axonometric_projection#/media/File:Comparison_of_graphical_projections.svg) we can observe this nice summary.

[image]

@hpekristiansen points out that the target perspective can be achieved by specifying the three unit vectors for the `x`, `y`, and `z` axis (as pointed out by the [TikZ manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) v3.1.9a, section 25.2 “The XY- and XYZ-Coordinate Systems”) through incremental steps and visual comparison.
Hence, the only line of code that @hpekristiansen has added is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[                       % from before
  x={(5,1)}, y={(0,4.3)}, z={(0.3,-0.8)},  % NEW
  …                                        % everything else as before
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagecolor{darkgray}\color{white}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
   x={(5,1)}, y={(0,4.3)}, z={(0.3,-0.8)},
   dot/.style = {
    fill, draw, circle,
    inner sep = 0,
    minimum size = 2pt,
  }
]

  \node [dot] (O) at (0, 0, 0) {};
  \filldraw [
    color = green,
    fill opacity = 0.25,
  ]
    (1,0,0) node [dot] (i) {} --
    (0,1,0) node [dot] (j) {} --
    (0,0,1) node [dot] (k) {} --
    cycle;
  \draw [->] (O) -- ($1.3*(i)$);
  \draw [->] (O) -- ($1.3*(j)$);
  \draw [->] (O) -- ($1.3*(k)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Coordinate system with triangle]

Comment: And how were the coordinates `x={(5,1)}, y={(0,4.3)}, z={(0.3,-0.8)}` computed?

Comment: They were not computed. -they were selected to match your request.

Comment: Hence, were they eyeballed? I'm just trying to understand what the proper way of handling TikZ fake 3D.

Comment: No - I did not make the comparisons visual at a distance(“eyeballed”). I did a direct comparison of compiled result and the wished result and stepped the parameters in steps of 0.1 until the result had smallest error.

Comment: I see. If you add this description to your answer, then I could accept it. Right now it's not very clear how my problem has been solved. Thanks again for your patience. (Also, thanks for the `border=1cm`. New trick to add to the collection.)

Comment: It is right now not clear how your problem has not been solved.

Comment: Did you read my comment?